# In a google script how do you find a string in a cell using a for Loop?

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I imagine this is relatively simple, but have tried a lot of things including `getDisplayValue()` and `getValue()`. I have code in Google Scripts where a user inputs a client name, then what's suppose to happen is the name is compared to all other names in a row and once the name is found the script proceeds to obtain data from that person's column.

Tried to `getValue` and `getDisplayValue` but I'm not finding the name

```
//chosenClient = a String inputted by user
//startMonth = int already inputted by user

//finds client in spreadsheet then sends month to them
function findClient(chosenClient, startMonth){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //search through column [get last column]
  var lastColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
 //Logger.log(lastColumn);
  for(var k = 1; k <=lastColumn; k++){
  //find chosenClient 
    var currColumn = sheet.getRange(4, k).getDisplayValue();  //WORK ON THIS~!
    Logger.log(currColumn);
    if(currColumn == chosenClient){
      LoggerLog(currColumn);
  gatherDates(k, startMonth);   //if client found activate getDat(startMonth)

    }else{
    //ui.alert('no such client found');  //if no client found send alert error
    }
  }

}
```

I hope script finds the client name in the spreadsheet and then proceeds to paste their relevant data into an email (but only need help with matching client name in sheet).

Below is sample of my sheet
[here is a link to a screenshot of spreadsheet. I tried to insert it into the post but it wouldn't work](https://photos.app.goo.gl/YoM8epF16uynAoEj6)

Comment: Please add sample data from the spreadsheet and from the user input.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with the script. `chosenClient`, a String inputted by user is inputted wrongly